More efficient way to color-code cycle permutation list
I would like to color-code a select group of numbers in a list containing sub-lists of varying lengths red and the remaining ones blue.
Here's a short example in which I use two For-loops that colors the roots numbers in mTest red and the remaining numbers in mTest blue and I was wondering if someone could suggest a more compact way of achieving this?  Both mTest and roots are variable sizes and mTest and roots are permutation cycles (no duplicates).
 mTest = {{7}, {2, 4}, {3, 8}, {12}, {5}, {1, 6, 9, 10}, {11}}
roots = {2, 8}
rootPos = 
 Flatten[Position[mTest, x_ /; x == #, Infinity] & /@ roots, 1]

colorVal = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length@mTest, i++,
 branch = {};
 For[j = 1, j <= Length@mTest[[i]], j++,
  If[MemberQ[rootPos, {i, j}],
   xVal = Style[mTest[[i, j]], Red];
   ,
   xVal = Style[mTest[[i, j]], Blue];
   ];
  AppendTo[branch, xVal];
  ];
 AppendTo[colorVal, branch];
 ]
colorVal

$$
\{\{\color{blue}7\},\{\color{red}2,\color{blue}4\},\{\color{blue}3,\color{red}8\},\{\color{blue}{12}\},\{\color{blue}5\},\{\color{blue}{1,6,9,10}\},\{\color{blue}{11}\}\}
$$

Possible duplicate of 197348.

@Syed:  Ok, thanks for the reference.  Was able to code it that way.  Will post my solution.

mTest = {{7}, {2, 4}, {3, 8}, {12}, {5}, {1, 6, 9, 10}, {11}};
roots = {2, 8};
pos = Position[mTest, Alternatives @@ roots];

MapIndexed[
 If[MemberQ[pos, #2], Style[#1, Red, Bold], 
   Style[#1, Blue]] &, mTest, {2}]




Very nice.  Good exercise for me.

As a learning aid, use MapIndexed[f, mTest, {2}] before you write the function itself. This allows you to see where it is getting mapped.

A replacement-based approach:
mTest /. {a_ /; MemberQ[roots, a] :> Style[a, Red], a_?NumericQ :> Style[a, Blue]}


Another way:
mTest = {{7}, {2, 4}, {3, 1, 8}, {16}, {5}};
roots = {2, 8, 16};

MapAt[Style[#, FontColor -> Red] &, Position[mTest, Alternatives @@ roots]] @*
MapAt[Style[#, FontColor -> Blue] &, Position[mTest, _Integer?(FreeQ[roots, #] &)]] @ 
  mTest

Same strategy but easier to see what's going on:
With[
  {blues = Position[mTest, _Integer?(FreeQ[roots, #] &)],
   reds = Position[mTest, Alternatives @@ roots]},
  Composition[
    MapAt[Style[#, FontColor -> Red] &, reds],
    MapAt[Style[#, FontColor -> Blue] &, blues]][mTest]]


As per @Syed's reference above, I was able to code it more compactly using MapAt, first mapping the red colors then mapping the blue colors.  Was not able to use a single MapAt to effect both blue and red colors in one operation though.  If someone's interested in coding it with one Map operation or fewer lines of code, I'll check it to close the thread.
 mTest = {{7}, {2, 4}, {3, 1, 8}, {16}, {5}}
roots = {2, 8, 16}
rootPos = 
 Flatten[Position[mTest, x_ /; x == #, Infinity] & /@ roots, 1]
uniqueElements = Flatten[mTest, 1]
allPos = 
 Flatten[Position[mTest, x_ /; x == #] & /@ uniqueElements, 1]
compPos = DeleteElements[allPos, rootPos];
list1 = MapAt[Style[#, FontColor -> Red] &, mTest, # & /@ rootPos]
list2 = MapAt[Style[#, FontColor -> Blue] &, list1, # & /@ compPos]
Print["New list: ", list2]

$$
\{\{\color{blue}{7}\},\{\color{red}{2},\color{blue}{4}\},\{\color{blue}{3},\color{blue}{1},\color{red}{8}\},\{\color{red}{16}\},\{\color{blue}{5}\}\}
$$
